# Setting the CSS version to 3.0 permanently in visual studio 2010 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make CSS 3.0 the Default in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Web Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323657/make-css-3-0-the-default-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-web-update)

I have certain CSS styles (v 3.0) that work fine while deployed but everytime I open up the project It gets reset to 2.1. Is there a way I can force it to use only CSS 3.0 ??
Is there a properties field somewhere that I could Change??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised I did not get any answers on this Question. 
Anyway here is credit to DaveHale23 of the forum for his post here

[Make CSS 3.0 the Default in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Web Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323657/make-css-3-0-the-default-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-web-update)

that helped me out. 
Once I installed this:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210

VS2010 remembered the 3.0 setting on reopening the project.